# SQl Server 2005: How to create a TSQL as per my business logic?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have two tables:-

### Table_01

- Table01ID (int)
- TestID (uniqueidentifier)
- TestDate  (Datetime)
- TestNo (varchar)

### Table_02

- Table02ID (int)
- TestID (Uniqueidentifier - Fk from Table01)
- TransDate (DateTIme)
- status = (int - 0 or 1)

Rules

1. Table_02 can have more than one record per TestID (FK)
2. So records per TestID have status = 1.
3. but once status is 0. (that means transaction done)

For Example (Table_02): -

```
Table02ID  TestID                                  TransDate                Status
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1          {21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D}  01-10-2010 11:30:00.000  1
2          {21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D}  01-10-2010 11:35:00.000  1
3          {21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D}  01-10-2010 11:40:00.000  1
4          {21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D}  01-10-2010 11:59:00.000  1
5          {21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D}  01-10-2010 12:20:00.000  0
```

Now I need:-

```
SELECT t.* 
FROM Table_01 t1
JOIN Table_02 t2 on t1.TestID = t2.TestID
WHERE 
     if t2.Status = 0 then Ignore the record (TestID)
     AND t2.Status = 1 then return only 1 Top Record order by t2.TransDate desc
```

I hope you guys got it what i mean :|. Please help?

Comment: Tell me if I got this right:  You want to get the latest record from Table_02 for each TestID and the matching record from Table_01 for it?

Comment: @Remus: Well. It looks like you answered my question, can you please elaborate it in an example? And Yes. thats what I need (the latest record)

Comment: The example below will get what you need

Comment: "Table_02 can have more than one record per TestID (FK)" - how is this possible when you set TestID as a uniqueidentifier in Table 02 as well?

Comment: @Roopesh: I'm guessing that "uniqueidentifier" refers to the type (i.e. GUID), but it is marked as a FK.

Comment: @Roopesh: Right its GUID

Comment: on the topic of uniqueidentifiers though, Table_01 probably doesn't need both Table01ID and TestID.  TestID is probably the best PK for the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Novice:  Here's how I'd do it.

```
Select * from Table_01 
Join
    (Select MAX(TransDate) as LatestDate, TestID, status from Table_02
            where TestID not in
                  (Select TestID from Table_02 where status = 0)
        group by TestID, status) as latestTrans 
on latestTrans.TestID = Table_01.TestID
order by latestTrans.LatestDate DESC
```

The middle part (lines 3-5) gets the latest record for each TestID (filtering out those you don't want) and creates a temporary table "latestTrans".  Joining this to the original Table_01 gives you all relevant Table_01 columns for each entry in the temporary table.

@Raymund's answer does the same thing with slightly different syntax.  I'm not sure which solution would perform better.  My script makes it easier to maintain as the "group by" statement won't grow if you need more columns from Table_01 to be returned and it is easier to add more join statements if need be.

**UPDATE**
I changed the script to take out any TestIDs where the status is 0.  The script's starting to look rather complex for a seemingly simple idea, but it's complicated in that you need to group the data twice, first by status and then by TestID (to get the MaxDate).

Note: I took out the check for status = 1 assuming all possible values for 'status' are 0 and 1. Put it back in if that's not the case.

Comment: It will return all the records from database coz every record has atleast one entry where Status = 1. See the Table_02 in my question, the last record's status is 0. I have to ignore those Test where they have an entry of Status 0. I need only those where there is no entry of Status 0 per record. Thanks in Advance man.

Comment: Oh, I see - you want to filter out any TestIDs from Table_02 where a status = 0 exists.  Right?

Comment: ya. Status is always either 0 or 1. Thanks again. I will try it soon and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT    t1.Table01ID, t1.TestNo, t1.TestDate, MAX(t2.TransDate), t2.TestID, t2.status
FROM         Table_02 t2 INNER JOIN
                      Table_01 t1 ON t2.TestID = t1.TestID
GROUP BY t2.status, t2.TestID, t1.Table01ID, t1.TestDate, t1.TestNo
HAVING      (t2.status = 1)
```